# WPF Button Pressed/Released Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am new to WPF and trying to do my best to follow the MVVM button Im struggling with a current problem
I have a view Model class

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    private bool _Reset;
    public bool Reset{ get{ return _Reset;} set {_Reset = value;} }
    ...
}
```

Now I want to bind a button so that if while Im pressing it _Reset is true and when I release it _Reset is false
I feel like the command pattern is alot of work for a simple on/off

Is there a way to bind the IsPressed of a button to a property from my data context

I want to do this as simple as possible because I have a dozen or so buttons all doing the type of thing just other properties

Comment: Because I know nothing about it.  Care to elaborate or example??

Answer (score 5):

So what you are going to need to do is import `System.Windows.Interactivity`.  Go to references, add reference, Assemblies, Extensions.  You will find it there.  Next add it to your project

`xmlns:inter="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`

you can now use the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` and `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` event.

```
<Button Content="Some Button">
        <inter:Interaction.Triggers>
            <inter:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                <inter:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ButtonDown}"/>
            </inter:EventTrigger>
            <inter:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
                <inter:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ButtonUp}"/>
            </inter:EventTrigger>
        </inter:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>

 public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ButtonDown = new RelayCommand(OnButtonDown);
        ButtonUp = new RelayCommand(OnButtonUp);
    }
    public RelayCommand ButtonDown { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand ButtonUp { get; set; }

    private void OnButtonUp()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Button Released");
    }

    private void OnButtonDown()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Button Pressed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If using .NET Core 3.1 / .NET 5.0 or higher, the [`System.Windows.Interactivity`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/2.0.20525?_src=template) has been deprecated, instead add the [`Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf`](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf) NuGet package to your project. The package works in a very similar way to the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35043222/21220396) for the.NET Framework 4.8.x or lower.

within your xaml header you'll need to add the reference to

```xml
<Control x:Class="YourNamespace.ControlName"
         ...
         xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
         ...>
```

Now you can decorate the button or other item which you are attempting to the event triggers, such as `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`.

```xml
<Button Content="Click Me.">
    <b:Interaction.Triggers>
        <b:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
             <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnButtonDown}"/>            
        </b:EventTrigger>
        <b:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
             <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnButtonUp}"/>            
        </b:EventTrigger>
    </b:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

This now allows for binding to a `System.Windows.Input.ICommand` property within your view-model class. In this example I am using the `RelayCommand` object form the [CommunityToolkitm.Mvvm](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet) and writing to the debug console, but this can be replaced inline with any call to static items, or if the action is not a static item, can be done within the constructor of you view-model class.

```
class ControlViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    //... 
    public ICommand OnButtonDown { get; } = new RelayCommand(()=> Debug.WriteLine("Button Down");
    public ICommand OnButtonUp { get; } = new RelayCommand(()=> Debug.WriteLine("Button Up");
    //...
}
```